# Scrapy gets NoneType Error when using Privoxy Proxy for Tor

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, polipo

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I tried Polipo, but it kept refusing Firefox's connections even if I added myself as allowedClient and hours of researching with no solution. So instead, I installed Privoxy and I verified it work with Firefox by going to the Tor website and it said Congrats this browser is configured to use Tor. This confirms that I should be able to scrape Tor websites.

However when I used Scrapy, I get an error that no one seems to have...?

```
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'myProject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
 'myProject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['myProject.pipelines.MysqlPipeline']
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [Tor] DEBUG: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10 <GET http://thehiddenwiki.org>
2016-07-14 02:43:34 [scrapy] ERROR: Error downloading <GET http://thehiddenwiki.org>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1126, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 45, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/__init__.py", line 65, in download_request
    return handler.download_request(request, spider)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 60, in download_request
    return agent.download_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 259, in download_request
    agent = self._get_agent(request, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/handlers/http11.py", line 239, in _get_agent
    _, _, proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyParams = _parse(proxy)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py", line 37, in _parse
    return _parsed_url_args(parsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py", line 20, in _parsed_url_args
    host = b(parsed.hostname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py", line 17, in <lambda>
    b = lambda s: to_bytes(s, encoding='ascii')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 117, in to_bytes
    'object, got %s' % type(text).__name__)
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a unicode, str or bytes object, got NoneType
```

I looked up this "to_byte" error but I go to the source code for Scrapy.

I know this code works without the proxy because it scraped my localhost website and other websites, but not Tor obviously since it's needs the proxy to access onion websites.

What is going on?

**Middlewares.py**

```
class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua  = random.choice(settings.get('USER_AGENT_LIST'))
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)
            #this is just to check which user agent is being used for request
            spider.log(
                u'User-Agent: {} {}'.format(request.headers.get('User-Agent'), request),
                level=log.DEBUG
            )

class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = settings.get('HTTP_PROXY')
```

**Settings.py**

```
USER_AGENT_LIST = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/16.0 Firefox/16.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10'
]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
     'myProject.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
     'myProject.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
     #'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None
    # Disable compression middleware, so the actual HTML pages are cached
}

HTTP_PROXY = 'localhost:8118'
```

Comment: Use `HTTP_PROXY = 'http://localhost:8118'`

Comment: And that sir was the answer. Feel fee to post it and I'll upvote you + mark as solution!

Comment: For the record, I created https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2127

Comment: Nice! May this help others along the way.

Comment: Apparently this question was answered otherwise, but I got the same error when I was hit by https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/1857 -- a nonstandard error code from the server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Internally, [Scrapy uses `urllib(2)`'s `_parse_proxy`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py#L32) to detect proxy settings. From [`urllib` docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html):

> The urlopen() function works transparently with proxies which do not require authentication. In a Unix or Windows environment, set the http_proxy, or ftp_proxy environment variables to a URL that identifies the proxy server before starting the Python interpreter.

```
% http_proxy="http://www.someproxy.com:3128"
% export http_proxy
% python
...
```

And when using `proxy` key in `meta`, Scrapy expects the same syntax, that is it must contain the scheme, for example `'http://localhost:8118'`.

[This is in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware), albeit a bit burried:

> You can also set the meta key `proxy` per-request, to a value like `http://some_proxy_server:port`.